# On the irreducibility of the polynomial $x^{n}−\alpha$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

> $\mathbb{k}$ is a field. $\alpha \in \mathbb{k}$. Prove that if 
>   polynomial $f (x)=x^{n} - 1$ has all the roots over $\mathbb{k}$, then
>   $g(x) = x^{n} - \alpha$ is either irreducible over $\mathbb{k}$ or 
>   $\exists d>1, d|n$, that $x^{d} - \alpha$ has at least one root over 
>   $\mathbb{k}$

So there exist $n$ elements of $\mathbb{k}$ of order $n$. And they are closed under multiplication $(ab)^{n} = a^{n}b^{n} = 1$. We have $1^{n} = 1$. And $(a^{-1})^{n} = (a^{n})^{-1} = 1$. So it's a group under multiplication. I don't know if it helps in solving this problem, but that's all that i've figured out. What i should do with $x^{n} - \alpha$?

Comment: The title is misleading. This is not true in general.

Comment: @DietrichBurde i was trying to be short. Your suggestion to edit it?

Comment: "On the irreducibility of the polynomial $x^n-a$".